# Apply CSS for the external page opened via window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am opening an external page upon click of a button. This is working by using window.open(), the requirement is to apply a specific CSS to the element of external page like changing the font color.

Can anyone please help me to understand on how to apply CSS to the elements of a external page after opening the external page using window.open()

Comment: Is the new page you're opening completely external to your project (such as opening www.google.com), or are you just opening a page of your project in a new tab? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Are you able to provide any code you're working with?

Comment: Thank you, it is completely external

Comment: I suppose only if page provides it to do so, like some api

Comment: <script>
  function dirtypop()
{
  var generator=window.open('https://www.samplepage.com','name','height=400,width=500'); 
  generator.document.head.innerText += '<style>.chat-win{color:red !important;}</style>';

  
}
</script>
<div>
  
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="dirtypop()">test</a>
</div>

Comment: If is it completely external you cannot apply any kind of css modifications

Comment: thanks again, is there any workaround we can apply to achieve this? The requirement is to change the color of a text and they confirmed that the class of element will not change in future

Comment: Homework in hacker school?

Comment: yeah, we tried to rebuild but other team insisting to use that external page and make this cosmetic change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, end of story. This is a security issue built into browsers so scripts from other sites cannot modify other pages. This would be a disaster if browsers allowed this.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the DOM of the child window by accessing the document property of the returned value of the window.open method.

Example:

```
var popup = window.open("test.html");
popup.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

There will be security issues to deal with when trying to achieve such a goal when the parent domain and child domain differ due to same origin policies.

Comment: Thank you, can you please help me with the syntax to target a class to apply the CSS

Comment: If your class name is "className" and you want to target the first index since getElementsByClassName returns an array it would be as follows:


popup.document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";